# Chebysshef coefficient Cos

Tags: calculus

Hi Could you  show to that
$$\frac{2}\pi \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\cos (x) T_n(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx=\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^n \left((-2)^n+2^n\right) J_n(1)$$